# Independent Triangles with Straight Lines

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, triangle

Your task is to create independent triangles (which means they do not have the same edge) by drawing straight lines as exemplified below:

[image]

In this example, there are $5$ lines and $5$ independent triangles and no triangle exists with the same edge with another triangle.

so,

> At least how many straight lines do you need to have $11$ independent triangles without having any triangle having the same edge as given above?

Comment: Is Independent triangles means there is at least one edge that is not touched by another triangle?

Comment: @rudra no edge is supposed to be common between two triangles at all in the graph.

Comment: It seems 12 independent lines are required though they can form 12 such triangles instead of required 11 :-(

Comment: Doing some search Oray, isnt KOBON triangle same as what you are asking?

Comment: @DEEM yes :) but asking this as a question is a puzzle itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created 11 independent triangles with ...

> ... **7 lines**:
>
>  [image: solution]

Answer (score 3):

with 7 lines [image] could be same as the previous answer

Comment: I got this before seeing previous answer. However I also found that something like this is defined as KOBON triangles?  I may be wrong